# Tooling API Bug? or my bad? INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE No access to entity 'anyobject__c'

Tags: apex, tooling-api, platform-bug

Anyone seen this error before with the tooling api? All references to custom objects generate errors from references to custom objects.  Only seems to apply to create calls, if I create it as an empty class then save, everything works fine.

## Example Apex Class

```
public with sharing class Example {
    public CustomObject__c obj;
}
```

## End Point

`POST /services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Are you working in Summer '14 instance?

Comment: Nope, on na7, which isn't up for summer '14 until July

Comment: Guess I'm the only one seeing this?

Comment: I think I've seen it before, not 100% sure though. I reckon it was when I used an older version of MavensMate and switching the tooling API setting off solved the problem... Are you using MavensMate here?